# Mongoosdb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```
var searchQuery = {}; //or something specific like {name: 'Kitten Name',name: ‘cat’;
var foundKittens = [];
Kitten.find(searchQuery , function (err, kittens) {
    if (err) 
         foundKittens = null
    } else {
        foundKittens = kittens
    }
});
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Searchquery has name with 2 values kitten or cat Both should be searchable…. How to define searchquery

Comment: Do you want search by exact name or by "contains" one name or another?

Comment: exactname with or condition

Comment: Kindly specify your issue/error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to search by one value or another like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "name": "Kitten Name"
    },
    {
      "name": "cat"
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NGpv4S8Hlyw)

Or if there are multiple options you can use alternativelly `$in` like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    "$in": [
      "cat",
      "Kitten Name"
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GfZbnPbD3cH)